# Is there a way to embed Excel charts on confluence?

Tags: jira

I am doing Scrum in my company. I need to create various reports/charts team wise and globally. The issue is since few fields are custom fields(example Team), I can't display/categorize the chart using these fields either on JIRA or Confluence(cloud). Also we want to display some data after doing calculations(example age of bug, % of work complete in Epic)
The solution I was thinking is to create charts in Excel the way I want and then just show/display them on Confluence.

Is this possible?Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

My Co-Founder created a detailed summary of all the possible options for [linking Jira data with reports and charts in Confluence](https://www.oldstreetsolutions.com/post/how-to-create-jira-reports-and-charts-in-confluence).

It includes some plugins (from Stiltsoft) that enable exactly what you're looking for.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Chris Cooke. Consider editing this answer to include the relevant information from the link that made you want to share it in the first place. Why? Simply because if the link becomes invalid, the answer as it is doesn't add any value to the community.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using the "Google Drive / Docs for Confluence" plugin (not free) to embed Google Sheets in Confluence pages. I don't know about specifically Excel sheets, though, but there might be a plugin for that too.